# How to override the vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php in magento2 app/code/ custom module

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, override-block

How to override the vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php file in magento2 app/code/ custom module

I'm updated the `const SWATCH_RENDERER_TEMPLATE = 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml';`

please provide any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use **preference** property to overirde the file. Like below code:

> Create file : [Vendor][Module]\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Rewrite\Product\Renderer\Configurable" />
</config>
```

> Create class
> [Vendor][Module]\Block\Rewrite\Product\Renderer\Configurable to
> override Magento block

```
<?php
    namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Rewrite\Product\Renderer;

    class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable
    {

        protected function getRendererTemplate()
        {
            return $this->isProductHasSwatchAttribute() ?
                self::SWATCH_RENDERER_TEMPLATE : '[Vendor]_[Module]::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml';
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this one but Not working @Amit Saini

Comment: Please add Magento_Swatches module in etc/module.xml in sequence tag for dependency and then run the upgrade and compile command.

Comment: added in Magento_Swatches module in etc/module.xml in sequence tag but
still not working @Amit Saini

Comment: @venkataprasad Please share your complete code.

Comment: it is working using plugin

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to over-ride in magento 2. 
Via Plugins, Observers and Events, Preferences 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ko75VJVor9I

Here is perfect video that will teach us all 3 ways to give override.